# AngularJS SPA using API and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, mongoose

I am creating a simple AngularJS SPA using an API to load data into Mongoose.

My app just adds, displays and edits a list of members. It works when I just store the members in an array in my factory service but now I want to change it to hook up to Mongoose via an API.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('SimpleFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    var factory = {};

    var members =  $http.get('/api/members') 


    factory.getMembers = function () 
    {
        return members = $http.get('/api/members');
    }

   factory.getMember = function (index) {
        if (index >=0 && index < members.length ) {
           return  members[index] = $http.get('/api/members/' + member_id )
       }
       return undefined
    }


    factory.addMember = function(member) {
         return $http.post('/api/members',member)
    }
    factory.updateMember = function(index,member) {
         $http.put('/api/members/' + member_id, member)
    }

    return factory;
}])
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MembersController', ['$scope','SimpleFactory',
   function ($scope,SimpleFactory) {


    SimpleFactory.getMembers()
    .success(function(members) {
    $scope.members = members;
    });


$scope.addMember = function()
{
    var member = {
        name: $scope.newMember.name,
        address: $scope.newMember.address,
        age : $scope.newMember.age,
        level : $scope.newMember.level,
        swimmer : $scope.newMember.swimmer,
        email : $scope.newMember.email,
        regdate : $scope.newMember.regdate,
                }

      SimpleFactory.addMember(member)
      .success(function(added_member) 
      { 
         $scope.members.push(added_member);
         $scope.newMember = { }
      }       );
}

}])
```

But I am not sure how to change my controller for updating a member, it is coded as follows to pick up the members from an array in my factory setting, how do I code it to pick up members from Mongoose via API:

```
app.controller('MemberDetailController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'SimpleFactory',
    function($scope, $location, $routeParams, SimpleFactory) {

        $scope.member = {
            index: $routeParams.member_index,
            detail: SimpleFactory.getMember($routeParams.member_index)
        }


        $scope.updateMember = function() {
            SimpleFactory.updateMember($scope.member.index,
                $scope.member.detail)
            $location.path('/members')
        }

    }
])
```

Can anyone help, its not a complicated app but I'm only learning and I am stuck here!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `$scope.member` object should set after getMember promise success.

**Code**

```
SimpleFactory.getMember($routeParams.member_index).then(function(data){
    $scope.member = {  
      index : $routeParams.member_index, 
      detail : data.user
    };
});
```

Apart from that you need to make sure `getMember` method should always return a promise while index is 0

```
   factory.getMember = function (index) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (index >=0 && index < members.length ) {
           return members[index] = $http.get('/api/members/' + member_id )
       }
       deferred.resolve;
    }
```

**Update**

For calling update method you need to do change service first which would return a promise

```
factory.updateMember = function(index,member) {
     return $http.put('/api/members/' + member_id, member)
}
```

Then call `factory.updateMember` resolve that promise  and then do `$location.path`

```
$scope.updateMember = function() {
    SimpleFactory.updateMember($scope.member.index, $scope.member.detail)
    .then(function(data) {
        $location.path('/members')
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks pankajpakar, and how do you think this should work to updateMember: ?


"$scope.updateMember = function() {
            SimpleFactory.updateMember($scope.member.index,
                $scope.member.detail)
            $location.path('/members')
        }"

Comment: @thirty take a look at updated answer & do upvote if it does help you, THanks :)

Comment: I have another question pankajparkar but no one has tried to answer yet! Could you have a look if you had a spare minute!

Comment: Thanks here u go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876253/simple-web-spa-with-api-and-mongoose-issue-with-ids